# How to clamp a quaternion to stay within a certain angle of another

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

We have one head object and one body object.
These two objects are separate children of one person object.

I need to make the head object rotate freely left and right which I've done.
I also need to make the body object rotate left and right with the head object ONLY if the difference of rotation between the two quaternions is +/- 90 degrees.

In other words, I should be able to move the head freely left and right, if the difference of rotation between the head and body is less than or greater than 90 degrees, then the body will start rotating with the head and stop if the rotation is within +/- 90 degrees. The body's rotation should not snap to the head's rotation but instead make sure it stays inside an invisible 180 degree cone that the head can rotate.

Comment: i dont understand some parts of your explanation, could you give a concrete sample..phase 1 start head and body are together at 0 degree.. phase 2 rotate to left some degree what happen and so on...i dont understand if body rotate automatically or not following the rotation of the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do something like this:

```
    var rotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    Head.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, rotation);
    var angle = Quaternion.Angle(Head.transform.rotation, Body.transform.rotation);
    Debug.Log(angle);
    if(angle > 90)
    {
        Body.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, rotation);
    }
```

It will also rotate when you look up or down past 90 degrees.  So it might be better to have input modify the angles, clamp the body angle, and set them into the rotations.

```
    var rotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    headAngle = headAngle + rotation;
    bodyAngle = Mathf.Clamp(bodyAngle, headAngle - 90, headAngle + 90);

    Head.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(headAngle, Vector3.up);
    Body.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(bodyAngle, Vector3.up);
```